# Find an element in a sub list, and when this element is found, append all other elements in the list to another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big list which contains other sub lists inside it, i want to find specific element in sub lists, and when i find the element in one of sub lists, i want to take other elements in this specific sub list and append it in another list.

```
big_list= [['A','B','C'], ['D','E','F'], ['Find this:','Get this','and that'], ['G','H','I'], ['Find this:','Try this','Try that']]
```

I have done this:

```
    New_list =[]
    prefixes = ('Find this:') #it's an element in a sub list
    for sub_list in big_list[:]:
        for element in sub_list[:]:
            if prefixes in element:
               New_list.append(element)
   print(New_list)
```

In my code the result is:

```
New_list = ['Find this:', 'Find this:']
```

i want to get the other elements in this specific list, so the result is:

```
New_list = ['Find this:','Get this','and that', 'Find this:','Try this','Try that']
```

Comment: how many elements are there in `prefixes`?

Comment: do you want to append only the elements found after the match or all elements of that sublist?

Comment: I want to search only for one sentence like ('project name'), when this sentence is found in any sub list, it append the whole sub list, not only this specific element

Comment: is `prefixes` a string or a list/tuple?

Comment: here i put prefixes as tuple

Comment: Thanks, my problem is fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you are making things unnecessarily complicated. The `in` in `if prefixes in element:` can directly search in lists.

```
New_list =[]
prefixes = 'Find this:' 
for sub_list in big_list:
    if prefixes in sub_list:
        New_list.append(sub_list)
print(New_list)
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do a deep copy of the `sub_lst` otherwise changes made to the `big_list` will also reflect in the `new_lst`.

```
from copy import deepcopy

prefix = "Find this:"
new_lst = [deepcopy(sub_lst) for sub_lst in big_list if prefix in sub_lst]
```

---

A little bit about [shallow and deep copy operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy).

- A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
  extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
  the original.
- A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
  inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.